# Is this pure redundancy or what is going on here?

Tags: command-line, bash

In a script I am trying to understand there are these two lines:

```bsh
cd "$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)"
root_path=$(pwd)
```

Are the two above merely a redundant version of the one following or what is exactly going on there?

```bsh
root_path=$(pwd -P)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `pwd` returns the current working directory, while `dirname -- "$0"` returns the path where the running script is located. They can be accidentally equivalent, but generally, they can be quite different.

```
cd "$dir1"         # <- $dir1 is now pwd
"$dir2"/script.sh  # <- $dir2 is the dirname of $0 inside of $0
```